# Pandas: compare rows of dataframe on the basis of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Following is the example dataset

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
data=[['Afghanistan','2015','5.1'],
  ['Afghanistan','2015','6.1'],
  ['Bahrain','2020',''],
  ['Bahrain','2020','32'],
  ['Bahrain','2021','32'],
  ['Bahrain','2022','32']],
columns=['Country', 'Reference Year', 'value'])
```

I want to compare the rows on the basis of columns and flag inconsistency. For example, if Country and Reference year is same between two rows and value is different, both should be flagged out as "invalid".

What I am trying is

```
df1['Validity'] = np.where((df1[['Country', 'Reference Year']] == df1[['Country', 'Reference Year']]) & df1['value'] != df1['value'],'Valid','Invalid')
```

This gives me an error "ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (6, 8)". I believe this should be possible by using iloc or loc. But couldn't figure out the right way to do it.

My expected output is "Invalid" for row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4 and "valid" for row 5 and row 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`groupby.transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['Validity'] = np.where(df1.groupby(['Country', 'Reference Year'])['value']
                              .transform('nunique').gt(1),
                           'Invalid', 'Valid')
```

Output:

```
       Country Reference Year value Validity
0  Afghanistan           2015   5.1  Invalid
1  Afghanistan           2015   6.1  Invalid
2      Bahrain           2020        Invalid
3      Bahrain           2020    32  Invalid
4      Bahrain           2021    32    Valid
5      Bahrain           2022    32    Valid
```

Intermediates:

```
       Country Reference Year value Validity  nunique     >1
0  Afghanistan           2015   5.1  Invalid        2   True
1  Afghanistan           2015   6.1  Invalid        2   True
2      Bahrain           2020        Invalid        2   True
3      Bahrain           2020    32  Invalid        2   True
4      Bahrain           2021    32    Valid        1  False
5      Bahrain           2022    32    Valid        1  False
```

Comment: I like the first approach, could you please help with gt(1) as I didn't understand that?

Comment: @khushbu `.gt(1)` is just the pandas way of doing `>1` (**G**reater **T**han)

Answer (score 0):

To compare rows based on specific columns and flag inconsistencies, you can use the groupby function in pandas along with the transform method to create a new column indicating whether each row is valid or invalid based on the criteria you specified. Here's how you can do it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
data=[
    ['Afghanistan', '2015', '5.1'],
    ['Afghanistan', '2015', '6.1'],
    ['Bahrain', '2020', ''],
    ['Bahrain', '2020', '32'],
    ['Bahrain', '2021', '32'],
    ['Bahrain', '2022', '32']
],
columns=['Country', 'Reference Year', 'value'])

def flag_inconsistencies(group):
    if len(group['value'].unique()) > 1:
        group['flag'] = 'invalid'
    else:
        group['flag'] = 'valid'
    return group

df1['flag'] = df1.groupby(['Country', 'Reference Year']).apply(flag_inconsistencies)['flag']
print(df1)
```